# Monoprice Drawing Tablet MP1060-HA60

Tags: gimp, inkscape, graphics-tablet, evdev

I've purchased this [model 6814 tablet from Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6814) and am trying to use it in Gimp and Inkscape in 14.04.

It [seems that previously](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1788415), there was a driver "wizardpen" for non-Wacom tablets which is no longer maintained and not available for Trusty or higher.

However, I noticed that in Gimp, the various axes of the tablet (X, Y, and pressure) were actually being detected correctly, but by default they were mapped incorrectly. It reports that the tablet actually has 5 axes; the first 2 never change and X, Y, Pressure are axes 3, 4, 5 respectively.

So I was able to get it working in Gimp, but in Inkscape it expects these axes to be 1, 2, and 3 with no apparent way to change them. (tried 0.84, as well as 0.91 from a later PPA).

So, is there a way that I can edit this at the "system" level in Ubuntu, so that it swaps the detected axes on the input device? Also, is it possible to use the tablet as a regular mouse, so that I don't have to switch from tablet to mouse & back when I want to pick different brushes, colors etc.? (Or perhaps this will start automatically working correctly when I get the axes fixed.)

Hopefully there is a "generic" way to accomplish this without needing anything specific to the tablet. It seems like maybe [evdev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/evdev.4.html) is capable of doing this, but I only see options for 2 axes and not 5.